# Crash : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ViewGroup.java:5986 android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, crash, admob

My game is Crashing on Android Device mostly on android 11.

I am using
Unity 3d : 2020.3.34f1.
Backend : il2cpp.
Admob : 7.0.2.
Firebase: 9.0.0.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:5986)
at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:5905)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.scrollToRectOrFocus(ViewRootImpl.java:3290)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2900)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2831)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2384)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1411)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6789)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6747)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I searched about this and find that this is because of admob banner but the solution i got is with Banner.java class in sources folder according to this [link](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/2353#issuecomment-1308012497).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please add your code to see if it's really your fault, but it looks to me like an error in Banner.java, there's little you can do except report it